# Using & and * interchangeably for dereferencing?

Tags: c

I am looking at the `getline()` function and its parameters and it's causing a little confusion for me regarding how the ampersand "&" and the dereference asterisk "*" are used.

I know that "*" is used to declare a pointer and then dereference it, and that "&" is used to reference the address of a variable. But what is happening when you use "&" to "dereference" a pointer similar to the line:

`characters = getline(&buffer,&bufsize,stdin);`

from the code below?

is it getting the address of the pointer? kind of like using the double asterisk ** ?

this chunk of code is from:
https://c-for-dummies.com/blog/?p=1112

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int input(char *s,int length);

int main()
{
    char *buffer;
    size_t bufsize = 32;
    size_t characters;

    buffer = (char *)malloc(bufsize * sizeof(char));
    if( buffer == NULL)
    {
        perror("Unable to allocate buffer");
        exit(1);
    }

    printf("Type something: ");
    characters = getline(&buffer,&bufsize,stdin);
    printf("%zu characters were read.\n",characters);
    printf("You typed: '%s'\n",buffer);

    return(0);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`&` in C is the inverse of `*`.

Take `char ch;` declaration as an example. It declares `ch` as a one-byte integral variable. Let's say that this variable happens to be stored at `0x80000000`.

When you say `ch = 65`, you are changing the value at location `0x80000000` to `65`.

`&` gives you the address where the variable is stored. `&ch` is therefore the pointer `0x80000000`. `char *pointerToCh; pointerToCh = &ch` will thus result in `pointerToCh` being `0x80000000`

`*` refers to the value at the pointer address. Thus, `*pointerToCh` is the same as `ch`. `*pointerToCh = *pointerToCh + 7` will change `ch` to `72`, since it is the same as `ch = ch + 7`. It also follows that `*(&ch)` is the same thing as `ch`.

There is a bit of a problem because `*` is also used in type declarations, to say that something is a pointer - as you've seen above in `char *pointerToCh`. The `*` here is not the same `*` as the one in `*pointerToCh = *pointerToCh + 7`: the first one makes pointer types; the second one dereferences a pointer.

Why do we do this? Because functions in C just copy parameters passed to them, so they can't change their parameters and have this change be propagated to the calling code. For example:

```
void uselesslyChange(char copyOfCh) {
  // copyOfCh is 65
  copyOfCh = 80;
  // copyOfCh is 80
}

char ch = 65;
uselesslyChange(ch);
// ch is still 65
```

However, if we know the address, we can change what's there (even if the address is just a copy).

```
void change(char* copyOfChPointer) {
  // copyOfChPointer is 0x80000000, and there's a 65 there
  *copyOfChPointer = 80;
  // copyOfChPointer is 0x80000000, and there's a 80 there
}

char ch = 65;
change(&ch);
// ch is now 80
```

So, your code. The important bit is to understand that `getline` is supposed to be able to change both the buffer (pointer to the first character of an allocated memory area) and the buffer size (integer) to reflect the size of the line being read (e.g. if the buffer is too small, `getline` will reallocate it somewhere else). In order to be able to change them, it needs to know their locations in memory, just like above. Thus, `getline` accepts a pointer to a pointer to character (`char **buffer`) and a pointer to a size (`size_t *bufsize`). Remember, `**` and `*` here is a *type*, not dereferencing operation.